# How to group messages in UITableView (Chat bubbles) in terms of dates (sections)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I have a chat application. Everything works fine except for when I am trying to group the chat messages into sections based on the dates of the messages. The first time the chatController is loaded everything is fetched fine and grouped accurately but the minute a new message is sent or received and the tableView reloads, everything is duplicated (the sections with the rows are duplicated again and again)

So I have a structure or data model like this:

```
struct Chats {
    let text, fromId, toId: String
    let isIncoming: Bool
    let date: Date

    init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        self.text = dictionary["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.toId = dictionary["toId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.date = dictionary["date"] as? Date ?? Date()
        self.isIncoming = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != self.fromId
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
var messagesFromServer = [Chats]()
var chatMessages = [[Chats]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
        fetchMessages()
    }

   fileprivate func fetchMessages(){
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let query = Firestore.firestore().collection("connections").document(currentUid).collection(connection.uid).order(by: "date")

        query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error{
                ProgressHUD.showError("Something went wrong. \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            snapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ (change) in
                if change.type == .added{
                    let dictionary = change.document.data()
                    self.messagesFromServer.append(.init(dictionary: dictionary))
                }
            })
            self.attemptToAssembleGroupedMessages { (assembled) in
                if assembled{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func attemptToAssembleGroupedMessages(completion: (Bool) -> ()){
        let groupedMessages = Dictionary(grouping: messagesFromServer) { (element) -> Date in
            return element.date.reduceToMonthDayYear()
        }

        // provide a sorting for the keys
        let sortedKeys = groupedMessages.keys.sorted()
        sortedKeys.forEach { (key) in
            let values = groupedMessages[key]
            chatMessages.append(values ?? [])
            let assembled: Bool = true
            completion(assembled)
        }
    }
```

**Explanation of what I have done:**
Basically I hit the database and store all messages and data into a variable messagesFromServer. This works fine. Problem happens when I try to group the contents of this variable based on date into a new variable which is chatMessages (This is done using the function **attempToAssembleGroupMessages**)

If you guys are interested in looking at how table view is fetching the data, here is the code:

```
extension ChatController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    //How many sections
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return chatMessages.count
    }

    //What is the view in each of these sections
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if let firstMessageInSection = chatMessages[section].first {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: firstMessageInSection.date)

            let label = ViewForDateHeaderLabel()
            label.text = dateString

            let containerView = UIView()
            containerView.addSubview(label)
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

            return containerView
        }
        return nil
    }

    //What is the height of the view in each of these Sections?
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    //How many rows in each section?
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return chatMessages[section].count
    }

    //What is in each of these rows?
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ChatCell
        let chatMessage = chatMessages[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.chatMessage = chatMessage
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are adding all messages in `chatMessages.append`, instead of only the new or changed ones.

Comment: A brute force solution could be to add `chatMessages = []` before the `sortedKeys` loop.

Comment: @koen: yes that's what I realised and tried right after I posted this question and it worked lol. Anyways will mark yours as the correct answer if you post the answer. Why do you say this is a brute force solution, you think there are better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are adding all messages in `chatMessages.append`, instead of only the new or changed ones. A brute force solution could be to add `chatMessages = []` before the `sortedKeys` loop.

You could also add some sort of time stamp to your messages, and then only add newer messages. Not sure which one would be more efficient or suitable for your specific case - you would have to test that yourself.

Comment: I'm interested to learn why this was downvoted. Open to understand how to improve the code.

Comment: I know..my comment was downvoted as well..it was the code I posted and also the fact that I posted that the code works

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was appending all the messages again and again to try and group them. A good solution that worked is to empty the array before performing the grouping operation.

```
fileprivate func attemptToAssembleGroupedMessages(completion: (Bool) -> ()){
        chatMessages.removeAll() //SOLUTION
        let groupedMessages = Dictionary(grouping: messagesFromServer) { (element) -> Date in
            return element.date.reduceToMonthDayYear()
        }

        // provide a sorting for the keys
        let sortedKeys = groupedMessages.keys.sorted()
        sortedKeys.forEach { (key) in
            let values = groupedMessages[key]
            chatMessages.append(values ?? [])
            let assembled: Bool = true
            completion(assembled)
        }
    }
```